# How to run CPU profile of a specific function using pprof?

Tags: go, profiling, cpu-usage, instrumentation, pprof

[This](https://blog.golang.org/pprof) blog details how to run CPU profile using pprof. When profiling, a function like `main` may disappear from the sample because pprof truncates the sample to the bottom 100 stack frames. This is documented:

> In fact the total for main.FindLoops and main.main should have been 100%, but each stack sample only includes the bottom 100 stack frames; during about a quarter of the samples, the recursive main.DFS function was more than 100 frames deeper than main.main so the complete trace was truncated.

The issue with is that I have a particular function I want to profile. The sampler reports it appearing something like 5% of the time but I know that's not accurate. Its frame on the stack must have been lost due to the truncation.

Is there a way I can profile a particular function and never truncate it from the stack frame sample? I want to know its true CPU profile out of 100%.

Comment: Run _only_ that function. Typically this is done in a benchmark for this function: `go test -run x -bench TheBenchmarkOfThatFunction --cpuprofile cpu.out`. Note that you cannot have pprof sample some function only. The only thing you can do is run just this function.

Comment: Other tools for profiling outside of pprof can be made to do this kind of instrumentation ... https://www.jaegertracing.io/ for example can be made to work on only particular functions